# How to Obtain Jenkins build number with Python script

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins

I am pipe-lining a python script to automate the process of updating a dashboard in Google Sheets. In order to update the dashboard, first the latest build number must be obtained through Jenkins as the build number is updated periodically. After obtaining the build no the related build no log files will be downloaded and eventually updating it into the dashboard. The current problem is I could not obtain the latest build no from Jenkins after researching from various examples online. The Jenkins page I am accessing is requiring credentials.

```
jenkins_server = Jenkins("url", username="username", password="pw")
my_job = jenkins_server.get_job('job_name')
last_build = my_job.get_last_buildnumber()
print(last_build)
```

I keep on obtaining errors like The job name is not found whilst it is exactly the same job name as the site.

Comment: What is the composition of your `url`?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the Jenkins build number using the requests and json module in your Python script.

**Sample script**

```
import requests
import json

credentials = '<username>, <api_token>'
url = '<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/api/json?tree=lastBuild[number]'
response = requests.get(url, auth=credentials, verify=False)
jsonData = response.json()
last_build_number = jsonData['lastBuild']['number']
```

Comment: I did a mistake by typing an extra "/" in the url. Problem is solved. Thanks all